# 38-sided space-filling polyhedron

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d, polyhedra, solid-geometry

There was an incomplete answer for [38-sided Engel space-filling polyhedron](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49925/3d-picture-of-the-38-sided-engel-space-filling-polyhedron). Actual coordinates were not given.

A new paper by Moritz W. Schmitt, [On Space Groups and Dirichlet–Voronoi
Stereohedra](http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000020464/dissertation_moritz_schmitt.pdf), seems to have most of an answer on page 135.

Within [space group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_space_groups) IT(214), $I4_132$, and with reduced fundamental domain 
$$1/8 \times ((0,0,0), (1,1,1),(-1,1,1), (-1,-1,1), \\(1,-1,1) (1,1,2), (-1,1,2), (-1,-1,2), (1,-1,2))$$

$f$-vector $(70,106,38)$, and generating grid point $(427/6984, 761/6984, 1421/6984)$, the 38-sided space-filling polyhedron can be generated.  The author also supplies the program [plesiohedron](https://github.com/moritzschmitt/plesiohedron).

I'm lost in the math of this paper.  Could someone explain how to how to generate the proper points with this?  I'm guessing I could then use those points and [Voronoi Diagrams in 3D](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/VoronoiDiagramsIn3D/) to generate the 38-sided Voronoi cells.

A version of the [Space Group List Project poster](https://crystalsymmetry.wordpress.com/2014/08/15/the-space-group-list-project-as-a-poster/) could likely be made with all the various honeycombs within this paper.

Comment: A related question, also unanswered: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138282/understanding-peter-engels-space-filling-tricontaoctahedron-what-is-the-notati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The images of $\left(\frac{427}{6984}, \frac{761}{6984}, \frac{1421}{6984}\right)$ under $I4_132$ indeed generate this polyhedron as their Voronoi cells.  I used [this description](https://stevedutch.net/symmetry/3dspacegrps/3dspgr212-214.htm) of $I4_132$ and wrote the Python program below that outputs the polyhedron’s vertices and faces in [OFF format](https://www.antiprism.com/programs/off_format.html).  As expected, it has 70 vertices, 38 faces, and 106 edges.

[image: picture]

```
import itertools

import numpy as np
import scipy.spatial

# generating point from https://refubium.fu-berlin.de/handle/fub188/10176
x0, y0, z0 = 427 / 6984, 761 / 6984, 1421 / 6984

# I4₁32 from https://stevedutch.net/symmetry/3dspacegrps/3dspgr212-214.htm
other_points = [
    (x2 + i, y2 + j, z2 + k)
    for x1, y1, z1 in [
        (x0, y0, z0),
        (x0 + 1 / 2, y0 + 1 / 2, z0 + 1 / 2),
    ]
    for x2, y2, z2 in [
        (x1, y1, z1),
        (x1, -y1, 1 / 2 - z1),
        (1 / 2 - x1, y1, -z1),
        (-x1, 1 / 2 - y1, z1),
        (z1, x1, y1),
        (-z1, 1 / 2 - x1, y1),
        (z1, -x1, 1 / 2 - y1),
        (1 / 2 - z1, x1, -y1),
        (y1, z1, x1),
        (1 / 2 - y1, z1, -x1),
        (-y1, 1 / 2 - z1, x1),
        (y1, -z1, 1 / 2 - x1),
        (3 / 4 + x1, 3 / 4 - z1, 1 / 4 + y1),
        (1 / 4 + x1, 3 / 4 + z1, 3 / 4 - y1),
        (1 / 4 - x1, 1 / 4 - z1, 1 / 4 - y1),
        (3 / 4 - x1, 1 / 4 + z1, 3 / 4 + y1),
        (1 / 4 + z1, 3 / 4 + y1, 3 / 4 - x1),
        (3 / 4 - z1, 1 / 4 + y1, 3 / 4 + x1),
        (1 / 4 - z1, 1 / 4 - y1, 1 / 4 - x1),
        (3 / 4 + z1, 3 / 4 - y1, 1 / 4 + x1),
        (3 / 4 - y1, 1 / 4 + x1, 3 / 4 + z1),
        (3 / 4 + y1, 3 / 4 - x1, 1 / 4 + z1),
        (1 / 4 - y1, 1 / 4 - x1, 1 / 4 - z1),
        (1 / 4 + y1, 3 / 4 + x1, 3 / 4 - z1),
    ]
    for i in range(int(x0 - x2 - 1.001), int(x0 - x2 + 2.001))
    for j in range(int(y0 - y2 - 1.001), int(y0 - y2 + 2.001))
    for k in range(int(z0 - z2 - 1.001), int(z0 - z2 + 2.001))
    if (x2 + i, y2 + j, z2 + k) != (x0, y0, z0)
]

hs = scipy.spatial.HalfspaceIntersection(
    np.array(
        [
            [
                2 * (x1 - x0),
                2 * (y1 - y0),
                2 * (z1 - z0),
                (x0 + x1) * (x0 - x1) + (y0 + y1) * (y0 - y1) + (z0 + z1) * (z0 - z1),
            ]
            for x1, y1, z1 in other_points
        ]
    ),
    np.array([x0, y0, z0]),
)

faces = []
for dual_facet in set(sum(hs.dual_facets, [])):
    adj = {}
    for i, j in itertools.combinations(
        (i for i in range(len(hs.dual_facets)) if dual_facet in hs.dual_facets[i]), 2
    ):
        if set(hs.dual_facets[i]) & set(hs.dual_facets[j]) - {dual_facet}:
            adj.setdefault(i, []).append(j)
            adj.setdefault(j, []).append(i)
    start = a = min(adj)
    b = min(adj[a])
    face = [a]
    while b != start:
        a, [b] = b, set(adj[b]) - {a}
        face.append(a)
    faces.append(face)

print("OFF")
print(len(hs.dual_facets), len(faces), sum(map(len, faces)) // 2)
for vertex in hs.intersections:
    print(*vertex)
for face in faces:
    print(len(face), *face)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVbdbpswFL7nKbxNmqANEEjUdpV6W21Xe4AqqpzECc7AIOx0gakX26PuRbpzbP4MdJEQ9jnfd/58fEhRqSQXq7c3nhV5qQhXrFR5nkrHaSTinBUVoZKIohXJHS@qQBZUcZo6zidyZIKVsBNHUuRcKHIo84wkShXyPgxLdjhv@TkLDmd/y8qUi2DPwoSKfcpCUEV3d2G0jG5vnMtyQSp46iV5IOv4loTk5svdekFub6JuHa3jdoO@v63//vm9im2XUrEXtj@rXRIIpkJZZRlTZRWu9hD1jh3LQur1sYyj2I@jdZCozMlVwspnnYGEAJ4cAj/3EpNrwiEwfJ8gOHz/8LTykJfkEoEOnjoiXDQkQ@yy8RZDKdAxgRi1/bru1g1603tAaKw9jzx0ri0PIPFRrK0Rf6RupS3Zt9X@ZcCcGq9BYpgWqR6QpmrUjuzORdTa9m21CQJVc6RW69vqUQHG7CbxYdBD9QqkazgPjMasjZGokU/jt9HXGt0y59CmTNHE9hi9mqCHtt@LxEb0kVxmbduZ9czLbNx2rP16voJ2HXo/85HYiGE152zbmQ3rMxe3Heuw9nMVtOsw7ILJ9eR4K0sqjsyFyYEXHBxgT0XBcglwMpRek1hL@/lxsukVAqsxvZVO6T9seo3AekxvpTadH96dbuTDgzXAnI3jJDgUrdkffKXpQU/UbwI@HJLtFM@Fq42LIqBlSSu3q20/uKY7/MXkCocX1mk4MS11herqXXWN6npObeYudJ12sjT9ChJXz@DKyE2VjVzP49rITfmikdmNtZt@CoafE8cmNZa6Gj31pd6AznOcAxRVf4Q2Dlren2n6jDKFliVTrjxnbiKDXiEXAPa8e22Z7k9A/vXaN@nCNFr3gQ92ebblguKJyf6QXD7u6ZSJkSPPw9axQ7IRTxzSILHJ9b4zDiwMfYoln@cUJ1D45Fcver23Sg5JBkDbswM9p8rlugABLQom9u7J@x/2ZGG5wUpF4d/NA6HwZFy4wDGKbS94opvm7kFAeD7UnOjPhKcMgHBvtJk@UgquthuAbhc6STSyNZnR1w6F5tpwaO9BtjLcQFsUJV7nj98fHz96zWbmfBYEhZoPa@yUjBYIXBijcIAh/tHQrfUCDcEuzRnywT2WJgfj5crADEXnDgRtbIhq3YLXK/1@e/sH)

Comment: I used this and it was pretty easy to refine it to exact values. Then I figured out how to surround it with copies of itself and made an animation. It went viral. https://wolfr.am/Engel-38