# A simple space-filler, not a plesiohedron

Tags: vector-spaces, polyhedra, solid-geometry, tiling, crystallography

I recently posted [Engel-38](https://wolfr.am/Engel-38), a 38-sided [plesiohedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plesiohedron) found by P. Engel in 1980. The [set of vertices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2231511/38-sided-space-filling-polyhedron) was a question here. A plesiohedron is a [space-filling polyhedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_polyhedron) that is also a Voronoi cell.

The plesiohedrons are a subset of [stereohedrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereohedron), which do not need to be Voronoi cells.

For this question, I'm looking for a simple convex space-filling polyhedron that meets a few requirements.

1. Fills space in a unique, obvious way. Cubes would fail, since columns of cubes can be skew to each other. The Engel-38 variations would fail because they are not obvious.
2. Let the spacefiller $S$ have arbitrary point $a$ inside, then surround $S$ with copies of itself using the method in 1. Connect $a$ to all corresponding $a'$ for a set of edges equal to the faces. For any $a$, there must be two or more edge-face pairs that are **not** perpendicular.

Is there a stereohedron that is somewhat obviously *not* a plesiohedron? (I know several complicated, non-obvious examples.)

The next step up would be a space-filling polyhedron which is not a stereohedron. A good example of this is the [Schmitt–Conway–Danzer biprism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gyrobifastigium). Are other examples of this type known?

Comment: I don't understand "Connect $a$ to all corresponding $a'$ for a set of edges equal to the faces" - are you assuming the polyhedron is convex?

Comment: For example, in a unit cube, the point (a,b,c) would connect to (a+1,b,c), (a-1,b,c), (a,b+1,c), (a,b-1,c), (a,b,c+1) and (a,b,c-1).  But all of these lines are perpendicular to the faces.  Added the word convex.

Comment: Take any reasonable unique space-filler (a truncated octahedron will do) and stretch it 10-fold along some arbitrary direction. How about that?

Comment: Ivan, I think that might work.  If there are two separate points that are centers for half the faces, then there isn't a single point, and the shape then is obviously not Voronoi.